# How does a hacker get access to the root user when disabling the sandbox in puppeteer, and what does it look like?

Tags: sandbox, root

You'll see stuff like the [first comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51038064/169992) that adding the `--no-sandbox` flag when launching puppeteer "is a giant security hole" (upvoted many times). [Puppeteer troubleshooting docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox) say "running without a sandbox is **strongly discouraged**". Yet, it appears that you must run with this flag on Google Cloud Run and AWS Lambda for some reason. So what is the problem again? And many examples on the web use this flag.

Those troubleshooting docs explain the alternatives to that flag, which don't work on the serverless cloud tools, but it might help in answering this question.

- Enable user namespace cloning (recommended, even though it also seems to introduce a lesser security hole).
- Setup setuid sandbox.

Can you explain in a little detail an example scenario of what a hacker can do if that flag is enabled (or if you don't know puppeteer, what it means to not have the sandbox)? I think it will help me as well as be a general source of truth for people looking to run a tool like puppeteer in production, what kinds of security holes it might introduce into your infrastructure.

A helpful scenario illustration would include *how* the hacker gains access to the root user on the operating system (at a high level), and what they can do with that access in practice? (Does it mean they can then steal your ENV variables set through Google Cloud Run, and gain access to all your credentials, and take down your app or run amok in running up your bill because they have all your private keys? Does it mean they can get access to your social security number or something? Or is it less than that, they can't get access to your keys, but they can get access to logs or something. I just don't know what the scope is of it....).

Comment: The sandbox is a security mechanism which minimizes the impact of bugs in the browser, which unfortunately still occur often. It is a part of a multilayered defense (defense in depth). The attacker still needs to exploit a bug in the browser even if sandbox is disabled, but with sandbox enabled most times no actual harm is done even when the bug can be exploited. This means there is no simple "... hacker gets access to root user ..." even with sandbox disabled.

Comment: without the sandbox any site can possibly gain access to local files.  Having said that, using puppeteer already bypasses the sandbox.  You have code running outside of the browser that creates a tunnel between locally running code and the browser's dev tools.  So even without that flag a malicious site (if visited) could possibly inject code that runs locally with the user who is running the puppeteer code's privileges.